# SwiftUI - animation determined by multiple properties doesn't animate, or updates weirdly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I made an extremely fun game where you toggle switches on and off. If all 3 are on, then the `Rectangle` should flash green. Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle1IsOn = false
    @State var toggle2IsOn = false
    @State var toggle3IsOn = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Toggle 1", isOn: $toggle1IsOn)
            Toggle("Toggle 2", isOn: $toggle2IsOn)
            Toggle("Toggle 3", isOn: $toggle3IsOn)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(
                    toggle1IsOn && toggle2IsOn && toggle3IsOn
                        ? Color.green /// if all 3 toggles turned on, then become green
                        : Color.gray
                )
                .animation(
                    toggle1IsOn && toggle2IsOn && toggle3IsOn
                        ? .default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                        : .default, /// remove forever animation if not all 3 toggles are on
                    value: toggle1IsOn
                )
        }
    }
}
```

The color changes to green, but sometimes the repeat-forever animation doesn't run. Also, sometimes I get a weird purple color that I didn't define anywhere in my code. What is happening?

[image: Toggling switches, once all 3 are on, rectangle becomes green]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `value` of `animation(_:value:)`.  From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:)):

> A value to monitor for changes.

You're only passing in the first property `toggle1IsOn`, so when the other ones are changed, the animation doesn't react. Instead, you should pass in the condition that causes the green to be shown:

```
value: toggle1IsOn && toggle2IsOn && toggle3IsOn
```

As long as `value` conforms to [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) it's fine. You can also move it into a separate property, `shouldFlash`, so you don't repeat code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle1IsOn = false
    @State var toggle2IsOn = false
    @State var toggle3IsOn = false

    var body: some View {
        
        /// accumulate into 1 constant
        let shouldFlash = toggle1IsOn && toggle2IsOn && toggle3IsOn
        
        VStack {
            Toggle("Toggle 1", isOn: $toggle1IsOn)
            Toggle("Toggle 2", isOn: $toggle2IsOn)
            Toggle("Toggle 3", isOn: $toggle3IsOn)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(
                    shouldFlash
                        ? Color.green
                        : Color.gray
                )
                .animation(
                    shouldFlash
                        ? .default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                        : .default,
                    value: shouldFlash /// here!
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Animation runs without issues]

Comment: This is an old issue with Swift, it has problem with 3 Boolean all together in same line.

Comment: @swiftPunk tested with only 2, still happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDJTw.png. But once I pass in `shouldFlash` it works again.

Comment: No! you did solve the issue with rendering view, not with making 3 to 1, making view wait to get shouldFlash makes your codes works, if you make it State or Binding maybe you get issue again

Answer (score 1):

It's not good idea to use ternary operator for animation. Try to separate green rectangle and flash rectangle

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle1IsOn = false
    @State var toggle2IsOn = false
    @State var toggle3IsOn = false
    
    @State private var flashRectangleDidAppear = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Toggle 1", isOn: $toggle1IsOn)
            Toggle("Toggle 2", isOn: $toggle2IsOn)
            Toggle("Toggle 3", isOn: $toggle3IsOn)

            if toggle1IsOn && toggle2IsOn && toggle3IsOn {
                flashRectangle
            } else {
                grayRectangle
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    var flashRectangle: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(flashRectangleDidAppear ? Color.green : Color.gray)
            .animation(.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: flashRectangleDidAppear)
            .onAppear {
                flashRectangleDidAppear.toggle()
            }
    }
    
    var grayRectangle: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work better than @aheze answer indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But "It's not good idea to use ternary operator for animation" - why?